# PWM controlled variable resistor

Tags: resistors, pwm, variable

I need to have variable resistor (from around 5kOhm to 100kOhm range).
The problem is that this "resistor" see 350V (rectified 230V mains).
The control signal is PWM and need to be isolated from "resistor" potential.
In the schematics is what I think right now.  The R2/R6 divider just provide reference voltage vich is buffered with IC2B and then divided by PWM duty with IC1G. This divided reference is then forwarded to constant current sink with IC2A. The only component have 350V across is T1. (I just put BC548 from library but that need to be some other)

Some other ideas?

---

Details:

I know that T1 will dissipate near 20W.
The device is a RCD/GFI tester. In most cases Rx will be connected to Line voltage and GND is actually PE(chaisiss).
For testing in AC mode there will be diode bridge so at Rx will be positive 350V.
For testing pulsed DC only diode will be in line to Rx.
For clean DC test the pulsed DC will be just filtered with a capacitor.
All these tests *can* be actually done with low voltage *but* it is required that all tripping currents must be delivered from line voltage.

[image]

Comment: Define the purpose and specs. T1 will get very hot as shown.  E.g. 350V * 50mA

Comment: yep, I can think of multiple ways to implement something that works as a "variable resistor", but none of them is really universal. I don't think we can help you well if you c don't tell us what the *job* of the resistor is.

Comment: Yes I know that T1 will dissipate near 20W. The device is some kind of RCD/GFI tester. In most cases Rx will be connected to Line voltage and GND is actually PE(chaisiss). For testing in AC mode there will be diode bridge so at Rx will be positive 350V. For testing pulsed DC only diode will be in line to Rx. For clean DC test the pulsed DC will be just filtered with capacitor. All that test can be actually done with low voltage but here are required that all tripping currents must be delivered from line voltage.

Comment: Please note that resistor R2 must support 300 V min  ... So 2 (or 3 ...) serial resistors "must" be used (see specification max voltage across).